# invalid date returns while using moment in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, momentjs

I am trying to display  date using `moment(new Date(info.ModifiedDate+'z')).local().format("MM-DD-YYYY [at] hh:mm A")` where `info.ModifiedDate is "2018-03-13T15:05:32.177"` in IE it is returning as "Invalid date" but in chrome it is returning properly. So, unable to find the solution

Comment: Use Moment to parse the date, not the native Date API, and give it the explicit format.

Comment: can you post some code. I tried using UTC but didnt worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`moment.utc(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) instead of JavaScript `Date`:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

[`moment.utc(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) accepts ISO 8601 format like `2018-03-13T15:05:32.177`.

```js
var info = {ModifiedDate: '2018-03-13T15:05:32.177'};
console.log( moment.utc(info.ModifiedDate).local().format("MM-DD-YYYY [at] hh:mm A") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```